How should Kafka and Spark's Structured Streaming results be inserted into Iceberg Table according to specific columns? Without Partition
I have already succeeded in setting up Spark's Session and streaming messages from Kafka's Topic.
kafka_stream_df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format('kafka') \
    .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', 'localhost:10000, localhost:10001, localhost:10002') \
    .option('subscribe', 'responses') \
    .option('startingOffsets', 'latest') \
    .load()

Then, went thourhg several conversion process to select only the data that acutally entered the iceberg table.
schema = StructType() \
    .add("event_date", StringType()) \
    .add("event_timestamp", LongType()) \
    .add("event_name", StringType()) \
    .add("projectKey", StringType()) \
    .add("customerKey", StringType()) \
    .add("GA4ResponseId", StringType()) \
    .add("exitFieldId", LongType()) \
    .add("surveyTimeStamp", LongType()) \
    .add("currentFieldId", LongType()) \
    .add("rejectionFieldId", LongType())

type_transformed_df = kafka_stream_df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
parsed_df = type_transformed_df.select(from_json(col("value"), schema).alias("data")) \
    .select(
        col("data.event_date"),
        col("data.event_timestamp"),
        col("data.event_name"),
        col("data.projectKey").alias("project_key"),
        col("data.customerKey").alias("customer_key"),
        col("data.GA4ResponseId").alias("ga4_response_id"),
        col("data.exitFieldId").alias("exit_field_id"),
        col("data.surveyTimeStamp").alias("survey_time_stamp"),
        col("data.currentFieldId").alias("current_field_id"),
        col("data.rejectionFieldId").alias("rejection_field_id")
    )

Now the important thing is In the transformed Streaming Dataframe, each row data must be inserted into the corresponding project key iceberg table.
It would be convenient to work with partition using the project_key column in Iceberg's Log Table, but it cannot be used for my product...........
All messages must be written quickly to the iceberg table.
What should I do?? What approaches are there?

Answer with code now.

Iceberg has partitioned and non-partitioned approach, but that is defined when creating an Iceberg table.
In your case / wish, you can:

insert to Iceberg without partitioning (bad fetch performance), or
insert to different Iceberg tables using foreachBatch with caching.

This is the standard approach for multiple sinks.
Need create and append mode both on writeTo. A standard approach when more so about tables than paths.



Assuming no upsert needed. But not fast, as need to check for table existence from Driver. With Databricks Community Edition have less options as well; with proper Cluster - Databricks or otherwise can adapt this soluton, but this below works and we note not such good performance had.
Single Catalog means simple writeTo statement will infer Iceberg format and thus no need to define all aspects, options.
Code
# Using Databricks Community Edition with restricted Catalog aspects and Library added for Iceberg and conf params set on  SparkSession.
# Hence different approach for table existency check. Would use otherwise `"... spark_catalog.tableExists.(tablename) ..."` Many issues with DB Community Edition.
# No statement made as to whether tables exist always or may need to be created.
# Partitioning is handier for the sake of performance.
# No location / path on create specified.
# Take out prints latterly.
# Schema evolution not considered, automatic if can be handled.

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat, lit

# Creating SparkSession, specify Iceberg format for spark_catalog here so we do not need to state format on writeTo.
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("SimulatedKafkaToMultipleIcebergSinks") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.type", "hadoop") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.warehouse", "dbfs:/ICEBERG_SO_QUESTION/") \
    .config("spark.sql.legacy.pathOptionBehavior.enabled", "true") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Simulate KAFKA via Rate
rate_stream = spark.readStream \
    .format("rate") \
    .option("rowsPerSecond", 1) \
    .load()

# Simulate data. Using table_id instead of project_key.
message_stream = rate_stream.select((rate_stream["value"] + 1000).alias("message_id"),               
                                     rate_stream["timestamp"].alias("event_time"),                    
                                     (concat(lit("ICEBERG_TABLE_"), rate_stream["value"] % 5)).alias("table_id")   
)

# Append or create and append data.
def append_data_dynamically(df, table_name):
    # Driver aspect needed in some way when these requirements prevail.
    # Using Databricks community edition with restrited Catalog aspects.
    # Hence different approach for table existency check. Would use otherwise "... spark_catalog.tableExists.(tablename) ..."
    
    # result = spark.sql(f"SHOW TABLES IN spark_catalog.default LIKE '{table_name}'").collect()
    #if len(result) == 0:  >>> DOES NOT WORK IN DATABRICKS COMMUNITY EDITION !!!, use alternative

    try:
       dbutils.fs.ls(f"dbfs:/ICEBERG_SO_QUESTION/default/{table_name}") 
       print("The Iceberg table exists, appending it.")
       df.writeTo(table_name).append()
    except Exception as e:
        print("The Iceberg table does not exist, creating it.")
        df.writeTo(table_name).create()
        # spark.sql(f"REFRESH TABLE spark_catalog.default '.{table_name}'") >>> Did not work in Community Edition either

# For a given Microbatch, a relatively expensive operation involving driver! But that is required. Multiple sinks with computations 
# have more processing than just writing the same batch as is to multiple sinks. Not stated if tables for projects exist.
# Id vs. name aspect noted.
def process_batch(df, batch_id):
    
    df = df.cache() 
    list_table_ids = df.select("table_id").distinct().collect()

    for unique_table_id in list_table_ids:
       table_id_value = unique_table_id['table_id']
       table_data_df = df.filter(col("table_id") == table_id_value)
       print(f"Writing to table_id: {table_id_value}") 
       append_data_dynamically(table_data_df, table_id_value)

# Standard query writeStream approach
query = message_stream.writeStream \
    .foreachBatch(process_batch) \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/checkpoints/") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()

Output to prove the point

What we really need is this with a proper cluster
 if not spark_catalog.default.tableExists(table_name):
    ...
 ...


Answer with code now.

Write to temporary files and bulk load
query = parsed_df.writeStream \
    .format("parquet") \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .option("path", "/path/to/temp_parquet_files") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/path/to/checkpoints/") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()

then periodically load temporary files into Iceberg
